# Issue that doesn't seem to fit the bounty system - any suggestions?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I asked this question some time ago, and have recieved no answers or comments...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3243258/does-libharu-allow-compound-paths-in-vector-artwork

I'm guessing that the answer is simply no, but that (like me) no-one was very confident of that answer. So...

The question is something I want, but it's not important or urgent. I therefore want to leave the question open indefinitely, just in case.

I'd also like to offer a bounty for either (1) anyone implementing that feature, or (2) advice that will save me substantial time if I decide to implement. Yes, I know a few points are very little reward for potentially a fair amount of work - but who knows, maybe it's easier than I'd guess, or maybe to someone its enough?

Based on the bounty advice in the FAQ, what I want to do seems to be in conflict with how the bounty system works. There's the seven days thing in particular - though the conflict isn't definite since it depends on upvoted new answers appearing.

I don't see this as a feature request, but any relevant advice, rationales etc gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a note to your question saying you'll award a bounty of X rep to anyone who gives you an answer satisfying those conditions, without actually starting the bounty until/unless you get such an answer. It's not really how the bounty system was designed, but I see no problem with it. Your question won't get on the featured list, but there's no way around that

Comment: I don't think it should be on the featured list anyway. It seems inappropriate.

Comment: But how can you give X rep to anyone like that? Can I give my rep to anyone I want? Also, it seems like it will be hard for him to promote the question if the question doesn't appear in the featured list or if it is not a new question. I imagine not many people will even see his old question if he simply adds a note to it.

Comment: @Vivi Well, he can create a bounty once someone posts an answer he likes and award it to them a day later. It doesn't feature it in any way, but that's the price you pay for not using bounties normally

Comment: WRT promotion, it seems wrong to compete for attention against people who have important/urgent issues to resolve.