# Please ban the [bounty] tag

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

There are currently [7 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bounty) tagged with this ridiculous tag. Because as if having your question featured on the "Featured" tab and having a blue bubble appear on the title isn't enough to tell anyone there's a bounty on this question, you just *have* to give it this tag...

Two of them are meta questions that have been migrated, the rest except one have or have previously had bounties placed on them. The only plausibly valid use of this is for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276672/what-bounty-sites-do-other-open-source-projects-use), and even then it's a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this tag has been blacklisted meaning that the issue no longer exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, it was already gone by the time I checked -- but I went ahead and ran destroy on it anyway so all traces of it were eradicated.

Comment: Despite the fact one can use a tag inappropriately, it doesn't necessary mean the tag itself is invalid. [This question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59214/issue-that-doesnt-seem-to-fit-the-bounty-system-any-suggestions) is a good example of when this tag might be useful.

Comment: @GSerg: This request only applies to SO, not to Meta.

Comment: @Jon: I'm not saying this tag should be applied to that very question. I'm saying it could be applied to questions *described* in that question - that is, SO questions where the OP would like to offer a bounty, but is not happy with the bounty system restrictions.

Comment: @GSerg: It's still a metatag in that context, which is disallowed.